# Can you explain an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure

New to Azure. I just don't understand what is an Azure subscription.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?b=17.06

Answer (score 3):

Subscriptions form the ultimate scale point for your Azure environment.  Azure has both "hard" and "soft" limits, soft limits can be changed with a simple service request, e.g. the number of cores in your subscription, hard limits cannot be altered.  These limits are set out at the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits.  Your Azure resources will reside in an Azure Subscription.

Further Subscriptions form an administrative & security boundary - you assign permissions at a subscription / resource group level, deploy policies to a subscription etc.

@Naveen is correct in they also form a billing entity, for PAYG your payment method will be associated with your subscription.  For a Company your subscription may be associated with an Enterprise Agreement which can contain many other subscriptions.

Governance guidance for Azure Subscriptions can be found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-subscription-governance

Answer (score 0):

An Azure subscription is your account / profile to access Microsoft Azure Cloud platform and services. Each subscription is associated with your business contact, billing information.

To do any with Azure platform you would doing - behind the scenes logically tagged to an Azure Subscription [either yours are your organization's]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/